# How the Big Bang/Inflation started?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Big Bang was the start of everything. At first, there was energy just confined to a small space. And then it expanded rapidly, which we call Inflation. But what caused this Inflation, and how that energy came there even?

I have also heard that this was because of a particle-antiparticle pair, but

Please tell if there are some other good theories answering these questions.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2355/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/390557/2451 and links therein.