# How was it possible for the big bang to occur?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, big-bang

I think the person who asked [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26435/) meant a different thing than any of the people who wrote an answer thought so I'm asking what I'm guessing the author probably really meant. If there is no beginning of time, how is it possible at all for the big bang to have occurred. According to one theory, when matter reaches the singularity, in an area the thickness of the Planck length, matter can enter a new universe. Perhaps the singularity created a new universe as soon as it formed that then started expanding at the speed of light. Isn't it possible to prove that theory wrong and show that no universe exists on the other side of the singularity so if there is no beginning of time, it shouldn't be at all possible for the big bang to have occurred in the first place.

Could the assumption that there is no beginning of time be wrong for the following reason? When the laws are for a universe with no beginning of time, it can end up that there's no solution to what happens in the universe and you can derive something like the assassin paradox in the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDOP0XynAzA but only if the laws keep a record of everything that happened before. I don't see a way to derive that paradox.

According to https://www.researchgate.net/publication/40273095_On_the_Possibility_of_Supertasks_in_General_Relativity, it might be possible to perform a hypercomputation. I see how simple laws could produce a chain of events of assending order of cause and effect and even an event that surpasses all of the events in that chain of cause and effect but don't see how it could possibly produce a backwards descending chain of cause and effect that starts some finite time in the past. Doesn't that mean we can't derive a paradox from the existence or inexistence of the beginning of time?

Comment: Relevant recent popular article,  [There Was No Big Bang Singularity](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2018/07/27/there-was-no-big-bang-singularity/#1e39e3ca7d81), from Ethan Siegel:  *"We are absolutely certain there was no singularity associated with the hot Big Bang, and there may not have even been a birth to space and time at all."*

Comment: Permalink: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10701-009-9390-x

Comment: @HalHollis The author contradicts himself: "*There may have been a singularity at the very beginning of space and time, with inflation arising after that, ...*" - The article is full of speculations accusing others of speculations. Not to be taken seriously.

Comment: @OndřejDvořák Why did you delete your answer? You have nothing to lose yet. Downvotes cannot take your score below zero. Perhaps it wasn't a correct answer, but it was an interesting one.

Comment: @safesphere, I don't see a contradiction between the statement "there was no singularity associated with the hot Big Bang" and the statement that you've quoted.  What contradiction do you see?

Comment: @HalHollis You don't see a contradiction betelween "*There was no singularity*" and "*There may have been a singularity*"?

Comment: @safesphere, *" there was no singularity associated with the hot Big Bang"* $\ne$ *"There was no singularity"* .

Comment: @HalHollis I don't think this article is worth discussing, but based on the author's arguments, your statement seems incorrect. He argues that the singularity would make the BB arbitrary hot. So according to him one does equal the other.