# How was the Big Bang possible if it was so dense even light cannot escape?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

Since the big bang comprises of all the particles in the universe in an extremely dense point, couldn't it to be said it would be the most massive black hole to ever exist? Since even light cannot escape and they can only evaporate via high energy radiation, how did all the particles during the big bang have the energy to overcome the gravity? Wouldn't they have to be moving faster than light?

Comment: No. A black hole is a 2-sphere, the Universe a 3-sphere. They are not at all the same.

Comment: Sorry I think I may have worded incorrectly; my meaning was that since all the mass were in one single point, it should be so dense that particles would need to be faster than light to spread out.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26435/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3294/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two general observations which might help.

First, the big bang "fireball" trapped light inside it not because gravity was so powerful, but instead because the temperature was so high that the photons of light could not travel very far before colliding with something that had an electric charge (electron-positron pairs were all over the place at that time).

Regarding the gravity argument, it's important to remember that the big bang did not start as an explosion *in* space which the bang then "filled", it was *space itself* which was expanding and carrying matter along with it.

You would probably benefit by reading Stephen Weinberg's book *The First Three Minutes*, which goes into all the ins and outs of the big bang in an easily-comprehended way.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @safesphere, thanks for asking, it is the first anniversary of my surgery and they caught it before it went metastatic. the growths in my liver which were initially interpreted as metastasies were instead benign cysts and I have been given my future back. happy new year to you- NN