# Is this a possible big-bang scenario?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, big-bang

Assume an universe with a single black hole that contains all the universe's mass and then let's wait for quite some time.

What happens if by Heisenberg's uncertainty principle a virtual particle/anti-particle pair jumps into existence, where the anti-particle goes into the black hole annihilating it, while the particle decays into a new universe.

Wouldn't this mimick the big-bang?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was the universe a black hole at the beginning?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20394/was-the-universe-a-black-hole-at-the-beginning)

Answer (score 1):

Black Holes and Big Bang seed are both singularity (and, may look similar), but they are fully different. Black Hole is singularity in Time (meaning, at singularity, space component from Spacetime vanishes and if you fall inside a Black Hole, singularity would be in your direct future), but Big Bang seed is singularity in Space (in rough words; Big Bang seed hasn't been fully understood).

So, a Black Hole can't be Big Bang seed. Big Bang seed didn't fire out particles. It expanded itself with Space. That's why we don't have a point in space where Big Bang happened. Big Bang happened everywhere.

There are some fictional theories saying Black Holes are Big Bang seeds of another universes, but if you talk only about solid theories and our universe, Black Holes can't mimic Big Bang seed. They can evaporate (Hawking radiation ju-ju), but mere evaporation can't make it Big Bang seed.

Comment: I forgot time, now I need some to think about it. Thanks (+1)

Comment: Hi, so you say that a Big Bang seed can make somthing that special (creating a unvisere!) because it's a singualrity in space? I see your point. A little more explanation would help...

Comment: @draks At Big Bang singularity, Time starts to behave like another direction of Space. And, I never said it's somehow special in creating the universe. I just told the difference.