# Was the mass of the universe the same when it first began as it is now?

Tags: black-holes, universe, big-bang

I've heard that the big bang began in all places at once, but my physics teacher told my class that the universe was all once compressed into a single dense piece of matter. If my physics teacher is right, then did that dense piece of matter have the same mass as the entire universe now? And if it was so small and yet to dense, wouldn't it technically have been a black hole?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20394/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given that matter cannot escape a black hole, how did the big bang produce the universe we see today?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26435/)

Comment: Mass could be understood as the rest mass of all the matter which can change from day to day. I bet you meant the total energy (including mass)...?