# Why didn't a black hole form right after the Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, big-bang

Why didn't a black hole form right after the Big Bang and the universe contract towards a singularity?

Comment: The short answer is that inflation during the inflationary epoch easily overpowered gravity.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_%28cosmology%29 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflationary_epoch

Comment: @BrandonEnright: No, inflation isn't necessary in order to explain this. Noninflationary GR doesn't predict that the universe recontracts.

Comment: duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3294/4552