# Entropy of the big bang

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, big-bang, equilibrium

At the moment of big bang, all the matter was in perfect order, that is entropy 0 so what force or disturbance would occur to begin the chaos and the entropy start to increase?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Usually it's a bad idea on stackexchange sites to ask more than one question within one question. Your first question already had an answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3294/  , so I edited it out.

Answer (score -1):

> At the moment of big bang, all the matter was in perfect order, that is entropy 0 [...]

This is not true as far as we know. We think it was in a state of less than maximum entropy (else heat death would have occurred instantly), but there is no reason to think it had 0 entropy. "Typical" initial conditions *would* have had maximum entropy.

> [...] so what force or disturbance would occur to begin the chaos and the entropy start to increase?

A force or disturbance is not necessary in order to make entropy increase.