# Big crunch scenario, would black holes form?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, spacetime, universe

Imagine a big crunch scenario in which everything (or almost everything as for I have other doubts, eg about entropy...) rolls back.

Shouldn't the contracting universe reach a point of density at which a black hole forms? Or, perhaps, as high density regions are and will be present, a point at which it fragments into several BHs?

In other words, shall singularities form before reaching the original one (or reaching a point very close to the singularity that our future description should avoid, of course)?

I think this might help understanding the expanding phase even if a big crunch isn't a realistic scenario. If the answer is yes, it would point out that a simple roll back as often presented is a naive approach and unsymmetric processes were at work.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/why-did-the-universe-not-collapse-to-a-black-hole-shortly-after-the-big-bang

Comment: Thanks @Ben Crowell.  But it is right the point as for the collapsing universe will have many "seeds" for local collapse(s)..