# Why didnt early universe collapse into black hole?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, universe, big-bang

Given the early universe was infinitely small, why didnt it immediately collapse into a blackhole before it had time to expand?

Comment: Because [the Big Bang did not happen at a point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did the universe not collapse to a black hole shortly after the big bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3294/)